# Assume simply connectivity without loss of generality

Tags: finite-groups, riemann-surfaces, connectedness

Let $X$ a connected Riemann surface and $G$ a finite group that acts *faithfully* and *holomorphically* on $X$. Further, let $x \in X$ a non-trivially stabilized point (we know these points are discrete), $U$ a neighborhood of $x$, such that $U \cap gU = \emptyset$ for all $g\notin G_x := \{g \in G : g.x=x\}$ and

$$V:= \bigcup_{g\in G_x} gU.$$

With this setup, my lecture notes say that we can assume *"without loss of generality"* that $V$ is simply connected. If not, we make $U$ smaller till $V$ has no wholes.

I have thought on this for a long time but I still don't know how to prove this easily. I could not find an counterexample either.
Probably one knows an "algorithm" that determines $U$ based on $x$ and $G$ such that $V$ is simply connected.

Comment: First, you mean Riemann surface — Riemannian means you have a Riemannian metric without a holomorphic structure. Even if $U$ is a disk, generally $V$ won't be connected. What if you take $\mathbb Z/2$ acting on $\mathbb CP^1$ by $z\mapsto 1/z$?